# extract elements from AppWidgetHostView

Tags: android

i'm developing a textual android launcher, i want to implement a widget host (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host), after i've attached the widget correctly i have an instance of AppWidgetHostView, now i want to extract the various (graphical) elements from the AppWidgetHostView.

i would like to know how i can get then the layout tree from AppWidgetHostView

example:

```
~ getTree(mAppWidgetHostView);
  -> LinearLayout
     -> TextView
     -> TextView
```

so: the final result will be like a function called getTree that accepts an AppWidgetHostView instance as parameter and returns the tree with the elements that are displayed in the widget